# left_join a grouped dataset dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

So I started with a dataset which has ID values for users. Each ID value may come up several times in the dataset, i.e. `ID: 77, 77, 77, 86, 86, 86, 86, 45, 45, ...`

What I did was `group_by(ID)` so that there would only be one ID value anywhere in the table (I also averaged another numerical variable in the process).  What I ended up with was this new dataset with ID and AvgValue, and the original dataset.  Now I want to join these two datasets in order to have my AvgValue as one column, and only one ID per user anywhere in the table.

Ex.

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1440 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Id                     : int  77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 ...
 $ Group                  : Factor w/ 6 levels " ","A","AA","C",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ Sex                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Age                    : Factor w/ 49 levels "11y 10m 22d",..: 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 ...
 $ Value                  : num  79.2 82.9 83 83.6 84.2 ...
```

Now I `group_by(ID)`

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   51 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Id: int  77 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 ...
 $ AvgValue     : num  90.1 95.4 94.9 96.4 77.4 ...
```

Now when I `left_join` I get,

```
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   1440 obs. of  6 variables:
     $ Id                     : int  77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 77 ...
     $ AvgValue               : num  90.1 90.1 90.1 90.1 90.1 ...
     $ Group                  : Factor w/ 6 levels " ","A","AA","C",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
     $ Sex                    : Factor w/ 2 levels "F","M": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
     $ Age                    : Factor w/ 49 levels "11y 10m 22d",..: 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 43 ...
     $ Value                  : num  79.2 82.9 83 83.6 84.2 ...
```

Instead of just having one row for each ID value.  Is this possible?

Comment: just `group_by(Id, group, Sex, Age)` and don't do the `left_join`

Comment: @HubertL but then it doesn't collapse the IDs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a distinct after you do the join.

```
res <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "Id") %>% distinct(Id)
```